# Issue in appending dynamic component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

The background of the problem I am facing I was getting the data and appending it to `innerHTML` of a `div`, it was getting appended, but the issue was custom directives (`appdropzone`, `appdroppable`, `approvable`) within
that `innerHTML` piece was not responding so
after researching I found it would never work this way, I'll have to create a dynamic component in order to make the custom directives working. (Please also let me know if this approach also would not work)

Therefore I referred the dynamic component section of [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#the-adcomponent-interface) and tried it out but I get an error on line

> `const adItem = this.ads[data1];` `this.ads is undefined

Please can someone point out the issue? Thanks

The error on console

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '<div 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" _ngcontent-c18="" appdropzone=""
 class="dropzone fs-settings__upload-section__floor-wrapper__preview- 
 image__image-area ng-star-inserted" id="toget" ng-reflect-ng-style=" 
 [object Object]"
 style="width: 100%; background-image: 
 url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANqyYtn1FAhKXkFi/hkQfuCuyO
 Lfk9ykpOc5CQnOcnR8n/9ySZhLa0CgAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background- 
 repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 
 100% 100%;"><!--bindings={
 "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
 }--><div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable="" class="box 
draggable movable ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none"
style="transform: translateX(136.8%) translateY(50.4%);"> vav3 </div><div 
_ ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable=""
class="box draggable movable ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none" 
style="transform: translateX(837.6%) translateY(3.20003%);"> vav5 </div>
<div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable="" class="box draggable 
movable
ng-star-inserted" touch-action="none" style="transform: 
translateX(639.2%) translateY(340.8%);"> vav54 </div>
<div _ngcontent-c18="" appdroppable="" appmovable="" class="box draggable 
movable ng-star-inserted"
touch-action="none" style="transform: translateX(-288.8%) 
translateY(276.8%);"> vav4 </div></div>' of undefined
```

The code

```
import { AdItem }      from './ad-item';
import { AdComponent } from './ad.component';
import { AvailableFloorDirective } from '@/shared/_directives';

export class abc implements OnInit {
    @Input() ads: AdItem[];
    @ViewChild(AvailableFloorDirective) availFloor: AvailableFloorDirective;
    gettingData() {
        this.xyzService('floorplans', (err, data1) = > {
                if (data1) {
                    const adItem = this.ads[data1];
                    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.
                    resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);
                    const viewContainerRef = this.availFloor.viewContainerRef;
                    viewContainerRef.clear();
                    const componentRef =
                        viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
                    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
    }

    }

   }
```

abc html

```
<div *ngIf="!onActive">
     <ng-template avail-floor></ng-template>
</div>
```

avail-floor.diecrtive

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[avail-floor]'
})

export class AvailableFloorDirective {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef){ }
}
```

ad.component

```
export interface AdComponent {
    data: any;
}
```

ad-item.ts

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

export class AdItem {
   constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data: any) {}
}
```

The response data should get rendered and my directives should work on that rendered element.

Comment: The link for angular stackblitz is:=  https://stackblitz.com/angular/bymkpbeeljb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your problem is that the variable 'adds' is undefined, which is an input passed to your 'abc' class. So you should check if this input is properly passed. This is so far not related with dynamic component instantiation.

Nb: your 'abc' class is not a component (@component missing), so unless specific configuration, I guess it is not linked to any template and, since Inputs are passed through templates, this is probbly the reason why your variable is undefined. I would suggest to refer to this : 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Yeah I know the @Input ads: AdItem[]; const adItem = this.ads[data1]; is giving me undefined but why it is giving error I am not able to figure it out, I tried giving the file in my module as well but no luck

Comment: I have done similar to Angular official , and also have imported as u can see in the code import { AdItem } from './ad-item'; .Also I am using Angular7, can that be an issue